# Can you have multiple lost and found directories?

Tags: filesystems, lost-found

I was unaware of the `mklost+found` command until I [read this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix).

The `mklost+found` command will make a new lost+found directory in the pwd.

1. Why would you ever need to run this command? The lost+found directory already exists in / on every distro I've checked.
2. What would happen if you have multiple lost and found directories? Would recovered data fragments go to the lost+found dir in / , or would it go to the most recently created lost+found dir?

I'm not sure how I could deliberately create a data fragment to test this.

Comment: `rm -rf /lost+found`.  Oops...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why would you ever need to run this command?

In case the `lost+found` directory doesn't exist. Since it's just an ordinary directory, the `root` user can remove it using `rm -r`. Some versions of `fsck`, when they need to make use of a `lost+found` directory, will create it if it doesn't exist, and some versions won't. If there's no `lost+found` directory, `fsck` can't recover orphaned files, that is, files that do not have any directory entries that refer to them.

The Linux version of `mklost+found` has the following feature (from the [mklost+found man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mklost+found)):

> `mklost+found` pre-allocates disk blocks to the lost+found directory so that when e2fsck(8) is being run to recover a filesystem, it does not need to allocate blocks in the filesystem to store a large number of unlinked files. This ensures that e2fsck will not have to allocate data blocks in the filesystem during recovery.

This means that, if you have to recover files from a damaged filesystem using `fsck`, fewer files will be lost as part of the recovery process because `fsck` won't need to allocate blocks from the filesystem; such blocks which may contain valid file data.

> What would happen if you have multiple lost and found directories?

For a given filesystem, `fsck` will only use one `lost+found` directory: the one that is at the filesystem's root directory. Any other `lost+found` directory will not be treated specially.

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Why would you ever need to run this command? The lost+found directory already exists in / on every distro I've checked.

Something needs to create the `lost+found`, this command would appear to do that. Every medium you mount needs to maintain its own `lost+found`.

*excerpt from man page*

> mklost+found  is used to create a lost+found directory in the current working directory on a Linux second extended file system.  There is normally a lost+found directory in the root directory of each filesystem.

What's the big deal with making a `lost+found` directory?

> mklost+found pre-allocates disk blocks to the lost+found directory so that when e2fsck(8) is being run to recover a filesystem, it does not need to allocate blocks in the filesystem to store a  large number of unlinked files.  This ensures that e2fsck will not have to allocate data blocks in the filesystem during recovery.

> Q2. What would happen if you have multiple lost and found directories? Would recovered data fragments go to the lost+found dir in / , or would it go to the most recently created lost+found dir?

I would expect that the last one would be the one that gets used by `e2fsck` if it needs to move data blocks to `lost+found`.

Comment: "Something needs to create the `lost+found`": Yes, but in most cases that command is `mke2fs`.

Answer (score 3):

"The lost+found directory already exists in `/` on every distro I've checked."

But that's not the point.  Every "real" filesystem (which maps to a block storage of some sort, as opposed to pseudo filesystems like /proc and swap) needs a lost+found orphanage.  For example, if you have a separate filesystem for /home, then there should be `/home/lost+found`.  This is because `fsck` won't move a file to `/lost+found` on the root filesystem; it leaves the files it finds where it found them, but creates a directory entry in the orphanage so that a human can intervene to arrange for the appropriate adoption.  Knowing that something is in `/home/lost+found` vs. `/var/lost+found` can make that manual intervention far easier.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Essential System Administration](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003432.do)

> Disk errors or incorrect system shutdown may cause files to become lost: lost files refer to disk locations that are marked as in use in the data structures on the disk, but that are not listed in any directory (e.g., a non-empty in ode that isn't listed in any directory). When the system is booting, it runs a program called fsck that, among other things, finds these files. There is a lost+found directory on every disk partition; /lost+found is the one on the root disk.

Most likely utilities such as fsck look put the file fragments in the lost+found directory inside the root of the respective partition. Other lost+found directories should be ignored.