# Login loop, bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to login to my elementaryOS and i stuck in a loop(i enter password, press enter and it back to login).
I entered the terminal (ctrl+alt+f3) to see what's going on with permissions, and i got the error:
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
so i checked my partition, and found got this:

```
Filesystem     Size  Used  Avail Use% Mounted on 
udev           3.9G     0   3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          787M  1.6M   785M   1% /run
/dev/sda5       17G   16G     0   100% /
tmpfs          3.9G     0   3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          5.0M  4.0K   5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          3.9G     0   3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     411M  411M      0  100% /snap/wine-platform/74
/dev/loop1      91M   91M      0  100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop3     174M  174M      0  100% /snap/spotify/34
/dev/loop2      98M   98M      0  100% /snap/docker/321
/dev/loop4     128K  128K      0  100% /snap/league/22
/dev/loop5     411M  411M      0  100% /snap/wine-platform/88
/dev/sda7       47G  4.0G    41G    9% /home
/dev/sda1      246M   31M   226M   13% /boot/efi
tmpfs          787M    0    787M    0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs          787M  4.0K   787M    1% /run/user/110
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Start from a Live USB and use `gparted` to allocate some space from sda7 to sda5. 17G is not enough for elementary root partition. I'd say with 25G you're on the safe side. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: But what is on the sda5? and why it installing stuff there and not to home?(where i allocated most of my ssd) how can i access whats on sda5 and delete?

Comment: The system and all installed programs are in `/`, not `/home` (where your personal data and the programs personal configuration files are). (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371593/the-different-uses-of-folders-in-the-root-directory).

Comment: Oh i see..i been mistaken then.. can i just uninstall some programs and get that space back for now? (Doesn't have usb thumb drive right now) how can i list all programs on root and uninstall them? Or even better, see which programs take most space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`17G` is usually not enough for the root partition of Ubuntu or its derivatives if you want to install some bigger software. I'd say with 25-30G you're on the safe side.

**Temporary Solution** to be able to log in again:
From terminal, try to remove some bigger software packages you don't need right now:

```
sudo apt remove some-big-software
```

Also it should be safe to remove files in `/tmp/` and `/var/log/` to gain some space to be able to login again

```
sudo rm -Rf /tmp/*
sudo rm -Rf /var/log/*
```

**Solution:**
Start from a Live USB and use `gparted` to allocate some space from `sda7` to `sda5`. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).