# What are the conditions that qualify a file as lost and found?

Tags: filesystems, fsck, e2fsck, lost-found

For files that `fsck` places in lost+found directory, under what circumstances does `fsck` consider a file to be lost, I have the following in my mind:

For regular files:

1) If the inode links count is 0. As described in this answer: [*"an inode with no corresponding file name."*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18157/233788)

2) When a file has no entry in any directory even if the inode link count isn't zero possibly to improper shutdown.

This also raises the question about lost directories. What can qualify a directory as being lost so that `fsck` places it in lost+found directory. Perhaps the directory's inode links count? Or when the directory doesn't have an entry in any other directory?

Answer (score 2):

I expect that it is just #2 (a file has no entry in any directory). 
If a file is pointed to by one or more directory entries,
`fsck` should just set the link count to equal the number of directory entries. 
If a file is pointed to by one or more directory entries,
there's no reason for `fsck` to create a new directory entry
in the `lost+found` directory.

Comment: A directory cannot possibly be lost? This is because it has at least two entries referring to it `..` and `.`